# Get the difference (additions and deletions) between two arrays / strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, comparison, difference

I've got an `array` which gets updated by user input (keyboard). I want to keep track of what entries change to get a better live performance.

Here an example:

```
// ascii values for 'Stuckoverflow'
var previousBlocks = [
     83, 116, 117, 99, 107, 111, 118,
     101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119
];

// ascii values for 'Stackedoverflow2014'
var blocks = [
     83, 116, 97, 99, 107, 101, 100, 111, 118,
     101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119,
     50, 48, 49, 52
];
```

I want to get the positions of entries that have been added or removed from `previousBlocks` to `blocks`. The larger unchanged part should remain intact. (In this case 'overflow')

```
var result = {
    deletions: [2],
    additions: [2, 5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16]
};
```

Human readable, the difference could be expressed like this:

```
St[-u][+a]ck[+e][+d]overflow[+2][+0][+1][+4]
```

Comment: See "Edit Distance" and/or "Dynamic Programming". Eg. http://cs.brynmawr.edu/Courses/cs330/spring2012/SpellingCheckers.pdf , http://bioinfo.ict.ac.cn/~dbu/AlgorithmCourses/Lectures/Lec6-EditDistance.pdf , http://alikhuram.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/dynamic-programming-edit-distance/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `array` gets manipulated by the user (by typing), changes are clustered. This solution calculates one range of changes and determines the replacement blocks. It is a very easy solution but it does its job.

```
var start = 0;
var end = 0;
var length = Math.min(previousBlocks.length, length);

// compare from left to right
while (
    start < length
    && previousBlocks[start]
        == blocks[start]
) {
    start ++;
}

// compare from right to left
while (
    end < length - start
    && previousBlocks[previousBlocks.length - end - 1]
        === blocks[blocks.length - end - 1]
) {
    end ++;
}

// collect the blocks that have been added
var rangeBlocks = [];
for (var i = start; i < blocks.length - end; i ++)
{
    rangeBlocks.push(blocks[i]);
}

return {
    // unchanged amount of blocks on the left
    startOffset: start,

    // unchanged amount of blocks on the right
    endOffset: end,

    // exchange / replace the changed part by these blocks
    blocks: rangeBlocks
};
```